# How to pass array to stored procedure in order to insert some records consecutively

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-types, table-valued-parameters

As everybody knows there is no array in SQL Server, there are some workarounds to achieve that somehow, like table-valued parameters (TVP) and user-defined data type (UDT) or even a parameter as comma-separated values (CSV).

There are also some examples on the internet that show how to use it, but most of them apply `SELECT` statement and use the parameter directly just like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetOrderList1
    (@OrderList VARCHAR(500))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(600)

    SET @SQL =  'SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate
                 FROM dbo.Orders
                 WHERE OrderID IN (' + @OrderList + ')'

    EXEC(@SQL)  
END
```

But I need to use an `INSERT` statement and use every single part of parameter one by one.

In my case I send a message to multiple participants by SignalR and I need to save it in data base too. Imagine I have a `MessageId` and I want to save it this way:

```
ID   |    MessageId   | ReceiverId
-----+----------------+-----------
     |                |
```

I need my stored procedure to get just one `MessageId` say 100 and multiple `ReceiverId`s say (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005) and insert them in related table one by one, something like this:

```
EXEC sp_AddToMessageReceivers 100, (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005)

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_AddToMessageReceivers
    @messageId INT, 
    @ReceiversIds VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT = 0

    WHILE @i < @ReceiversIds.length
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[MessageReceiver] (MessageId, ReceiverIds)
        VALUES (@MessageId, @ReceiversIds[i])

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
END
```

I know how to get the table valued parameter in stored procedure but I don't know how to work with them one by one in a while loop.

I really appropriate it if you offer a solution for this problem.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I would note some caution with your first example in the question - concatenating and executing dynamic SQL like this is a good way to open up some nice sql injection issues in your application.

Comment: Thanks @Paddy, but No, it's not supposed to compromise anything since I populate a `List<int> receiverIds` in C# codes and join all of them by a ',' character to make a CSV, so it's impossible to make a SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `1-Many` relationship `DataTable` from your application side and pass it as `Table Value Parameter` to your `Stored Procedure` and then you can insert into the table.

For example, first create a TVP with `MessageId` and `ReceiverId`

```
CREATE TYPE MessageTableType AS TABLE   
(
MessageId int,
ReceiverId int
)
```

Then create your Stored Procedure like this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddToMessageReceivers
    @MsgTvp MessageTableType readonly
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[MessageReceiver] 
        SELECT MessageId, ReceiverId from @MsgTvp
END
```

Then create a DataTable from your application side (assuming C# application) and pass it to the Stored Procedure.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("MessageId", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("ReceiverId", typeof(int));
//dataTable.Rows.Add.. Add rows here
```

Comment: Plus one for this - this will be more performant than the CSV versions above, as well as being more strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either create a table value function that returns a table form from csv values.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_csvToColumns]
    (@CommadelimitedString NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE (Value VARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    -- Fill the table variable with the rows for your result set
    DECLARE @IntLocation INT

    WHILE (CHARINDEX(',',    @CommadelimitedString, 0) > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @IntLocation =   CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @CommadelimitedString, 0)      

        INSERT INTO @Result (Value)
            --LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are   removed
            SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@CommadelimitedString, 0, @IntLocation)))   

        SET @CommadelimitedString = STUFF(@CommadelimitedString, 1, @IntLocation, '') 
    END

    INSERT INTO @Result (Value)
        SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(@CommadelimitedString))--LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank     spaces are removed

    DELETE FROM @Result 
    WHERE Value = ''

    RETURN 
END
```

Alter your stored procedure to use above function:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_AddToMessageReceivers
    @messageId INT, 
    @ReceiversIds VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp TABLE (tempid INT)

    INSERT INTO @temp(tempid)
        SELECT value 
        FROM dbo.fn_csvToColumns(@ReceiversIds, ',')

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 null FROM @temp)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @ReceiverIds = tempid 
        FROM @temp

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[MessageReceiver] (MessageId, ReceiverIds)
        VALUES (@MessageId, @ReceiverIds)

        DELETE FROM @temp 
        WHERE tempid = @ReceiverIds
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a split function (good examples can be found [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)).

Example:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (messageId, ReceiversId)
SELECT @messageId, fn_ssm.Item
FROM dbo.SplitStrings_Moden fn_ssm (@ReceiversIds, N',')
```

I strongly vote against any method using WHILE loops or the like, especially nestes loops like the example above since this might affect the code performance significantly!